# Confused about facebook graph api upgrade

Tags: cordova, facebook-graph-api

I have a cordova app that allows users to login using their facebook credentials. I recently received the following message from Facebook:

> "Your App" currently has access to
>   Graph API v2.9 which will reach the end of its 2-year lifetime on 22
>   July, 2019.We estimate 1 endpoint in total will be impacted by this
>   change and may stop working after the automatic upgrade push. To
>   ensure a smooth transition, please migrate all calls to Graph API
>   v2.10 or higher. Use the [API Upgrade Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning) to understand exactly how
>   this change will impact your app.

So I go to the [API Upgrade Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning) and see this:

[image]

The only graph API method that I'm using is

```
{user-id}/?fields=first_name,last_name,email
```

so I'm a little stumped as to why I'm getting this email. I do use a cordova plugin called [`cordova-plugin-facebook-4`](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4) to implement facebook authentication. Not sure if that plugin is calling the APIs behind the scenes.

It seems that upgrading to the latest version of `cordova-plugin-facebook4` solves the issue because it uses the latest version of the Facebook SDK and API. However, I'd prefer not to have to release a new version of the app if possible.

To that end, I noticed this setting:

[image]

Would changing that setting fix this issue without having to release a new version of the app?

Finally I noticed the following text in the table above:

> GET {application-id}2.0
>   GET {user-id}/permissions2.0
>   Starts enforcing the app's restrictions (such as country or age ) on API calls made without the application's 'appsecret_proof' in the request.

And there is the following setting, which is currently set to **No**:

[image]

Is it possible I could fix all this be simply switching that over to **Yes**?

I guess to summarize my questions, I want to know:

1. What am I getting this warning?
2. Will adjusting the **Upgrade API Version** values fix it?
3. Will setting the **New Version Features** to Yes fix it?

Comment: When an API version gets shut down, your app will automatically use the next lowest available version. The Upgrade API Calls buttons are there so that you can test what boosting your app to a different API version does upfront (that’s what you should use the button that upgrades this for app roles for, to be able to test your app before such a change becomes mandatory), and to apply this change for all users, when you are satisfied your app works correctly with the chosen version. They would also allow you to explicitly switch to a newer API version, than whatever the current lowest one is.

Answer (score 2):

1) You are getting this notifications because your app uses these endpoints

2) No, upgrading the API calls won't help since this only upgrades the endpoint version, not the actual calls made/fields requested. This would only help you to see if the plugin works with v2.10 or higher versions

3) No, this won't simply fix all possible issues

However looking in the mentioned endpoints and the fact you just use this plugin for login it may continue to work just fine since you are not required to update to the latest available API version, but only v2.10. You can use the "upgrade API calls" setting to test this.

However updating to the latest available version of the plugin and the plugin's suggested API version sounds like the way to go, since even v2.10 will only be available until November this year.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm a bit confused. Are you saying that changing `Upgrade API Calls` might fix it or that it won't?

Comment: Upgrading the API calls will just allow you to test if the plugin works with that API version.